# SSIS from oracle to sql server date format running in visual studio vs ssms

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ssis

I'm getting different date formats in my destination date column 'creation_date' when running my ssis packages in visual studio vs running them in ssms.

1. oracle source date format is MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS, however column type is set to VARCHAR2, unfortunetly i don't have authorisation to set a datetime format:

[image]

2. the package runs great in visual studio, i use an ado.net source where i specify the sql command:

```
select record_id, to_char(to_date(creation_Date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') creation_date
```

3. date column gets imported the way i want:

[image]

4. but when running the same package in ssms, the format gets switched:

[image]

Comment: Is your column in SQL Server properly typed? If so, the format means nothing; date and time data types have no format they are binary values. It's up to the presentation layer that determines the format of the date. The *real* problem is your Oracle database, and that it's using a `varchar2` to store date and time values; that's just bad design.

Comment: Yep destination column is datetime. But how running the package in VS date gets imported in the right format and in ssms it doesn't?

Comment: Also, *if* you are inserting *literal* strings into a date and time data type in SQL Server, make sure you are using the format `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` as these are the *only* formats that are unambiguous regardless of your language settings and the data type.

Comment: Presumably you are using an ambiguous literal string format, and you are using different language settings for your connections in VS and SSMS. If your Oracle data type was correct, this problem wouldn't happen, as the value would be interpreted as what it is *meant* to be; a date and time value.

Comment: Will give it a go using `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: That isn't unambiguous though...

Comment: I know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm just the destination owner, can't touch the source

Comment: Then you need to speak to whomever can correct the package to get them to make the package use either of the unambiguous formats I stated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use strings to store date values.

---

Currently, you are having to convert from string-to-date-to-string at the source and then string-to-datetime at the destination.

Since you cannot change your `VARCHAR2` data type in the source, don't pass your date data as strings between databases; use a `DATE` data type:

```sql
SELECT record_id, 
       to_date(creation_Date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS creation_date
FROM   your_table
```

Then you can handle the value as a `DATETIME` data type in the destination without having an intermediate string format to manage.